# Record name route to cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-cloudfront, wildcard-subdomain

My cloudfront distribution have `"*.example.com"` as **CNAMEs** and a loadbalancer as origin.
I route traffic from my route53 records directly to my cloudfront distribution **domain name**.
Some records have  subsubdomain named randomly. So they look like this: `"sub1.sub2.example.com"`, `"sub3.sub4.example.com"`.
I don't know if it is ok because sub1 and sub3 are subsubdomain so they are not contain in `"*.example.com"`.
Will it work ? By working i mean: The traffic sent to my records will be sent to cloudfront then to my loadbalancer without any issue?

edit: sub3 and sub4 are random.

Answer (score 1):

See [Using Custom URLs for Files by Adding Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) and [CNAME Wildcard support for Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/wildcard-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/)

The CloudFront distribution can be configured to handle alternate domains. This could be "*.example.com" for all subdomains and should cover the sub sub domains as well. Alternatively, you should be able to setup "*.sub2.example.com, *.sub4.example.com" if only the sub sub domain varies randomly.

In addition, CNAME records need to be setup in Route53 to resolve "*.example.com" to your CloudFront distribution.

Also worth noting that if you are using HTTPS alternate domain names must be covered by valid SSL/TLS certificates